# CSS glitchy on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a forum for my website, in order to make it easier for users to browse the forum, I made it so that the anchor tag contains the title and description (h2 and p) of the post. That way, people have a much larger area to click in order to get to the thread, which would be good for mobile.

On my CSS I have:

```
.forums a:hover{text-decoration: none;}
.forums a:hover>h3, .forums a:hover>h2{text-decoration: underline;}
```

Forum threads are inside divs, that have display: table, table-cell, and so on. There are no accidentally nested elements (would be noticeable).

However, on Chrome (and only on Chrome). When I hover over one of these links, it will do one of three things. Work properly, underline multiple thread titles, or not underline anything at all. (Tried changing anchor tags to div tags, just to see if it was a problem with that, but same odd behavior is seen).
I've even tested it on different computers, but problem still arises.

Is there any fix to this? I was thinking of replacing the h2 tags with anchor tags, and then having javascript deal with clicks on the table-cell... but would rather stay away from that.

Comment: Do you have a test for this like a jsfiddle?

Comment: From your code it seems you have declared the h3 and h2 inside the <a>. Why dont you try doing the reverse. Add h3 inside <a> tag.

Comment: @Riddler I have both h2 and p inside an <a> tag. This is so that the <a> tag fills the entire table cell. Not just a part of it.

Comment: Then as Patrick said seriously we need some code.

Comment: Trying to replicate on jsfiddle... but not working. Here's a link to page: http://209.126.111.226/forum/ @Riddler

Comment: If you want just the title to be underlined without the description, then i think it is working fine on my chrome.

Comment: @Riddler Did you hover over all the categories? Find that the first few work fine, but gets worse further down you go (or if you go, up and down the list)... but could be just a problem with my version of chrome.